# How to write a partitioned Parquet file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I'm trying to write a Pandas dataframe to a partitioned file:

```
df.to_parquet('output.parquet', engine='pyarrow', partition_cols = ['partone', 'partwo'])

TypeError: __cinit__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_cols'
```

From the documentation I expected that the `partition_cols` would be passed as a kwargs to the pyarrow library. How can a partitioned file be written to local disk using pandas?

Comment: Are you sure there is not a typo in the `partitiol_cols` argument?

Comment: Yeah, this was not the problem. Notice that the error message was correct.

Comment: `partition_cols` has been added in pandas 0.24.0: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html

Answer (score 24):

First make sure that you have a reasonably recent version of pandas and pyarrow:

```
pyenv shell 3.8.2
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install pandas pyarrow
pip freeze | grep pandas # pandas==1.2.3
pip freeze | grep pyarrow # pyarrow==3.0.0
```

Then you can use `partition_cols` to produce the partitioned parquet files:

```
import pandas as pd

# example dataframe with 3 rows and columns year,month,day,value
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'year':  [2020, 2020, 2021],
                        'month': [1,12,2], 
                        'day':   [1,31,28], 
                        'value': [1000,2000,3000]})

df.to_parquet('./mydf', partition_cols=['year', 'month', 'day'])
```

This produces:

```
mydf/year=2020/month=1/day=1/6f0258e6c48a48dbb56cae0494adf659.parquet
mydf/year=2020/month=12/day=31/cf8a45116d8441668c3a397b816cd5f3.parquet
mydf/year=2021/month=2/day=28/7f9ba3f37cb9417a8689290d3f5f9e6e.parquet
```

Answer (score 18):

Pandas `DataFrame.to_parquet` is a thin wrapper over `table = pa.Table.from_pandas(...)` and `pq.write_table(table, ...)` (see [`pandas.parquet.py#L120`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/bdb7a1603f1e0948ca0cab011987f616e7296167/pandas/io/parquet.py#L120)), and [`pq.write_table`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html) does not support writing partitioned datasets. You should use `pq.write_to_dataset` instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pd.DataFrame(yourData)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

pq.write_to_dataset(
    table,
    root_path='output.parquet',
    partition_cols=['partone', 'parttwo'],
)
```

For more info, see [pyarrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html?highlight=partition_cols#writing-to-partitioned-datasets).

In general, I would always use the PyArrow API directly when reading / writing parquet files, since the Pandas wrapper is rather limited in what it can do.

Comment: I believe that I did with the `engine=pyarrow` option, and it seems that the default engine is `pyarrow` and not `fastparquet`: "engine : {‘auto’, ‘pyarrow’, ‘fastparquet’}, default ‘auto’

    Parquet library to use. If ‘auto’, then the option io.parquet.engine is used. The default io.parquet.engine behavior is to try ‘pyarrow’, falling back to ‘fastparquet’ if ‘pyarrow’ is unavailable." https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html

Comment: Yes, you are right. They must have changed it in one of the recent versions.

Comment: Recent `pandas` has incorporated `partitioned_cols` and starts using `write_to_dataset` as well.

Answer (score 9):

You need to update to Pandas version 0.24 or above. The functionality of partition_cols is added from that version onwards.